# MySQL bug with bindings. Error 1452

Tags: mysql

Executing SQL script in server

> ERROR: Error 1452: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>
> ```
> (`aptechniy_sklad4`.`zayavka`, CONSTRAINT `zayavka-zakupivlia1`
>    FOREIGN KEY (`nomer_zayavku`) 
>    REFERENCES `zakupivlia` (`nomer_zayavku`) 
>    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
> ```

SQL Code:

```
INSERT INTO `aptechniy_sklad4`.`zayavka` 
  (`nomer_zayavku`, `data_skaladnnia`, `nomer apteku`, `data_vukonannia`) 
  VALUES (100001, '2017-01-03', 0001, '2017-01-05')
```

> SQL script execution finished: statements: 40 succeeded, 1 failed

Fetching back view definitions in final form.
Nothing to fetch

Answer (score 0):

The DB manager complains that you have a foreign constraint on field `nomer_zayavku` but you're trying to insert a row with value `100001` which does not exist in `zakupivlia` table.

Please check your table data first